# Draw coloured dot using WebGL

Tags: canvas, graph, webgl

Somehow, I can't seem to be able to find an answer to such a simple question - draw a songle dot using webGL.

Specifically, I'm using folowing function to draw 3D graph (however, the Z axis is represented by a color):

[image: Sample of the grapg]

Do not get confused by the word "3D" - I want no real 3D, I just want to produce image above using webGL.

Every pixel row is generated from an array, Y axis represents time.

Here you can see how I populate the data now:

```
       //Normal canvas rendering
       for(var i=0, l=data.length;i<l;i++) {
            h_ctx.beginPath();
            //The color of the dot
            h_ctx.fillStyle = "hsl("+(120-120*(data[i]/255))+", 100%, 45%)";
            //Create a dot using color above
            h_ctx.rect(i,iteration,1, 1);
            h_ctx.fill();
            h_ctx.closePath();
        }
```

If you want to see it in action, I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/Jer8t/). It requires support of AudioContext.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. If you just want to draw that image in WebGL then yes, the easiest way is to put those pixels in a texture and draw the texture. If you actually want to draw dots then there's [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765017/opengl-point-functionality-in-webgl/14771927#14771927)  The better question is why do you want to do this in WebGL? What's wrong with your canvas 2d solution you posted?

Comment: It's slow, that is wrong. I've seen some WebGL demos proving that WebGL rendering is faster (maybe it's double buffered...?). Also, I wan't to start learning webGL. I have already one map editor based on canvas that is wery slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to get big amounts of data into your shader would be as a texture. If your audio analyser already is a typed Uint8Array so you can just pass it to WebGL like you would pass a texture.

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,16,16,0,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,yourDataArray)
```

You could of course draw rectangles "almost" like you do it in the 2d context, which may be an easier transition into since it's in almost all tutorials the first thing you do. In WebGL a rectangle is defined by a 2 triangles, 3 vertices each. The color can be defined in many ways, but the closest to the 2d context would be to use per-vertex-color.

So you need an buffer an array with the coordinates for each of the 6 vertices (ranging from -1.0 to 1.0) . Keep in mind that in WebGL the Y axis is flipped <3, so 1 is down and -1 is up. Then you buffer an array with the 4 colors (r,g,b,a) for each of the 6 vertices (ranging from 0.0 to 1.0).

You repeat that for each of the rectangles, batch them to a single draw call and then draw them to the screen (you could draw them individually but that may lag if you do it 1024 times every frame).

Then you of course need to write basic vertex and a fragment shaders. For the vertex shader there isn't much to say it's a basic per vertex color shader passing the color attribute to the fragment shader in a varying vec4 for each vertex and calculating the vertex position in space based on your vertex position attribute.

Good thing for the gpu, if you already supplied the coordinates ranging from -1 to 1 it doesn't need to calculate much, bad for you since the gpu could easily also take the coordinates in screenspace (ranging from 0 to your screen dimension in pixels) and calculate the corresponding coordinates in clipspace (-1 to 1) at this point. In order to do so it needs to know the dimensions of your screen, which you supply via a uniform vec2.

The fragment shader then just takes the varying vec4 the vertex shaders supplied and just sets the fragColor (pixelcolor) based on it without any additional calculations. (unlike in the very first approach I suggested where you would supply the sound frequencies as a texture and almost everything else would happen in the fragment shader)

So you see drawing rectangles is super easy in WebGL and I am super horrible at explaining it. But I could give you a link to a tutorial that explains it much better and offers code snippets to play around with.

http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-fundamentals/

Comment: Thanks for writing all this. I'm sure I'll return to this post more than once :) As of the first function, the one that just acceptss array - how does it know what the values mean?

Comment: It doesn't know what the values mean. The data will be basically get interpreted as a 16x16 texture in RGBA (you define the dimensions and the color in the call to `texImage2d`) so that's what you'll start out with in the fragment shader. Since the sound data already comes as an array of 1024 unsigned ints (each 0-255 like color values in a texture) it basically is the same as image data. (1024 / 4 colors = 256 pixels = 16*16 texture)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is exactly a simple question. Drawing a point on the screen requires at least some sort of an overview of the rendering pipeline.

You need something to draw that point with. For example, you can create vertices and render them with gl_PointSize which will rasterize the point to the size that you specify.  By controlling this vertex or vertices, you can render points wherever you want on screen, when you want them.